# Adding more prototype cells to iOS storyboard than fit in viewcontroller dimensions?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard, prototype

I'm working on an iOS project with storyboards and have run into a problem I can't readily solve.

It's a basic viewcontroller that contains a tableview with custom cells. I have 5 prototype cells varying in height between 70 - 160 pixels and that's all fine - but I now need to add in some more prototypes and my issue is that there is no screen space for them - so I can't work on the design.

I imagined there would be a way to layout the storyboard such that the prototype cells can be displayed where I want them, rather than being visually constrained inside the view controller - which is rather limiting to put it mildly, but I can't figure out how to do it and the documentation seems to avoid the issue.

This graphic hopefully clarifies - I want to add new prototypes but they don't fit in the VC frame and so I can't edit them :-(

[image: Storyboard with Dynamic Prototype Cells]

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious ... but what might it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply scroll in that table view in Interface Builder. You won't be able to see them all at once, but you can scroll up and down to make other prototypes visible.

Comment: Doh! Brilliant, thanks Scott, I knew it had to be something simple! I guess I missed that because my screen is quite small so I'm usually scrolling the main IB window and I didn't try selecting the table and then just scrolling that. Obvious when you think about it ...

Comment: I added a 5th cell type, and some of mine are pretty tall (plus I have a big tableHeaderView), and it won't let me scroll any more. Seems like there's some kind of limit on the scrolling.

Comment: @shim: I think that's a bug actually. I've noticed the same thing when I create add a cell somewhere in section 1 or 2. If the table view is tall enough, suddenly the last cell can't be scrolled to anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Select a cell of the tableview in your storyboard, then scroll on your mouse/trackpad to reveal the hidden cells !

If you just select the view controller, you won't be able to scroll the tableview.

Answer (score -1):

Increase the height of your tableview. Then change the value y ordinate using Size Inspector to some negative value.